# New password and confirm password "doesn't match" Or "don't match"

Tags: grammar, questions

Which is grammatically correct for using on the website?

New password and confirm password "doesn't match" Or "don't match".

Comment: Please give the original with an attributed link. As it stands, this looks ungrammatical so asking for the correct option is unfelicitous. Is 'confirm password' short for 'input in the "confirm password" dialogue box'? If so, quotes are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> New password and confirm password "doesn't match" Or "don't match".

**In this case the subject is plural so use "don't"**

If you want to use "doesn't" then you can rewrite as follows in order to have a singular subject.

Confirm password doesn't match New password (singular subject)

Answer (score 1):

These are obviously two separate "things", calling for *don't* thus.